# Arabic Character not recognenized in centos using JasperReports

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to print a PDF file that contains arabic characters in CentOS environment. This Work like a charm in Windows 7.

Here is my JRXML file that contains the used font:

```
        <textField>
            <reportElement key="" x="264" y="10" width="320" height="21" uuid="d7c106cd-74c4-4283-97d0-9c3de426ca68"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="10" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

I tried to put the Arial font in the jasper extensions and edit the font.xml file but still doesn't work.

I have also put the ttf files in the classpath and in the jdk/jre/lib/fonts but no way.

I'm sure that in the CentOS environment, the Arabic language is supported. I Think that I should understand the way that jasper load their fonts and used it.

Comment: `I have also put the ttf files in the classpath and in the jdk/jre/lib/fonts but no way.` - Did you try to use *[Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper Reports PDF doesn't export cyrillic values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041619/jasper-reports-pdf-doesnt-export-cyrillic-values) & [Ukraine (Cyrilic) characters not displaying in Jasper Report PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5093749/876298) & [Jasper report in displaying arabic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32265647/876298) & [How to show arabic,Hebrew,etc language fonts on jasper (iReport) reports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23359978/876298)